# Hide Total Row in Rep[orting services

Tags: service, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report with total lines after a show is being reported.
A show may run a week or several weeks. I want to hide the total line when there is only 1 week for the show but display the total line when there are more than one week.  The example below should hide the Total row for "An American In Paris" but show for the other shows because they run for more than 1 week.I group by performance, week, start date.

I have tried:

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!week_performance.Value)<=1,True,False)
```

and

```
=IIF((Fields!week_performance.Value)<=1,True,False)
```

neither seems to work, even if `week = 1` the total line still shows

```
Performance             week    sales
A Gentlemens guide to Love & Murder 1   1500
                    2   2000
                    Total   3500
An American in Paris            1   1800
                    Total   1800
First Date              1   1900
                    2   2100
                    3   1800
                    Total   58000
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the CountRows() function. In this case, using it as follows will default to the current scope (i.e., the group of the showing, in this case) and should count just 1.

```
=IIF(CountRows() = 1,true,false)
```

In addition to CountRows(), if you had some unique value per showing, you could use the following:

```
=IIF(CountDistinct(Fields!UniqueID.Value) = 1,true,false)
```

If this doesn't work, reply as a comment and I'll do my best to help.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I used your second suggestion with CountDistinct and looks like it's working great.

Comment: If you feel my answer was correct, please mark it as the correct answer and upvote it. Thanks!